Is this equation of the GARCH(1,1) model correct?
I am new to the GRACH model and have read many papers, but I am confused about the equation provided below. Is the equation (15) correct? If the $z_{t}$ is the error, why does the author define them as a residual and then use them to fit the copula model? Based on my understanding, the $\alpha$ coefficient must be multiplied by the error and not the standard deviation. 

This is incorrect in the sense that the equations do not yield a GARCH(1,1) model. Instead of
$$\sigma_t^2 = \alpha\sigma_{t-1}^2+\beta z_{t-1}^2 + \gamma$$
it should be
$$\sigma_t^2 = \alpha\sigma_{t-1}^2 z_{t-1}^2 + \beta \sigma_{t-1}^2 + \gamma.$$
It is common to give $\sigma_{t} z_{t}$ a name such as $\varepsilon_t := \sigma_{t} z_{t}$ so that the equation becomes
$$\sigma_t^2 = \alpha\varepsilon_{t-1}^2+\beta\sigma_{t-1}^2 + \gamma.$$
